# How to change the file name when uploading a file in PHP

Tags: php

I have my upload file script here working.

Just want to know how I can change it to change the filename to the format of:

> `$var_####.ext` where `$var` is a variable I set, the `####` are a **random 4 digit number that is generated and the ext is the original file name's extension**.

Have seen other post about this but not quite sure how to put it all together into my script

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 5000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    header( 'Location: photo_upload.php?error=1&jobno=' . $jobno) ;
  } else {

    if (file_exists("upload_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
     header( 'Location: photo_upload.php?error=2&jobno=' . $jobno) ;
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

You just have to do:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload_images/" . THE_NAME_YOU_WANT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just edit your move_uploaded_file

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload_images/" . $var . '_' . rand(1000, 9999) . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$extension="type_of_file";    //whatever type you want
$var="file_name_you_want".".".$extension;  // put whatever name you want to set
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload_images/" . $var);
```

Comment: your post has been flagged as low-quality. please provide some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Just rename the file name with

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"])
```

See the code below to rename the file

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename="new_file".end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
upload_images/" . $newfilename);
```